# What is the correct syntax for changing fonts and drawing strings in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, drawstring, fontmetrics

Can someone check my syntax here? I am passing "Times New Roman","Arial","Verdana" to `fontName` and using 8,12,15 etc. for `fontSize`. It never changes the font here. I am doing this to write some text over an image.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(photo, 0, 0, null);
g2d.setColor(Color.white);
Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
g2d.setFont(font);
g2d.drawString(text,x,y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out that none of fonts from my list were there on the system so I had to use getAllFonts() method and pass only those fonts from the list .

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
    w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(photo, 0, 0, null);
g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
//example :     g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
g2d.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, size));
String s = "Hello, world!";
// assuming x & y is set using graphic's font metrics
g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
g2d.dispose();
```

Excerpt from sun documentation

> getGraphics
>
> public Graphics getGraphics() This
>   method returns a Graphics2D, but is
>   here for backwards compatibility.
>   createGraphics is more convenient,
>   since it is declared to return a
>   Graphics2D.

This does not really mean that you should not use `getGraphics` API. Just that the above code worked for me :)